# SharePoint 2013 Workflow Started But Not Doing Anything

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I have 2 workflows to start when a list item is created.  One is a 2010 workflow and the other is a 2013 workflow.

The 2013 workflow is supposed to grab the text of a lookup column and performs a "Replace substring in string action" to populate the modified substring into a multi-line text column.

For some reason the 2013 workflow will start and get stuck without progressing.  I was wondering if this is due to the replace substring in string action function.

Comment: Is it suspended? Is there any error? Try adding some logs to history list after workflow starts.

Comment: Not suspended, no errors.  I added some logs to the history list after the workflow starts.  The 2013 workflow is waiting for column A to equal Go before it begins its steps.  I verified that column A is set to Go but the 2013 workflow requires an item to be updated again for it to work.  Odd thing once I "brute force" the first workflow it will work fine for the new items for a while until it starts hanging again.